# How to make svg animation scaling from the center and not upper-left corner?

Tags: reactjs, animation, svg, svg-animate

I am using `animateTransform` to animate the scale of an `svg` in `ReactJs`.

The problem is that the animation starts from the upper-left corner but I need it to start from the center.

Here is my code

```
<g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <EmojiEvents style={{ color: "gold", fontSize: 60 }} />
                  </g>
                  <animateTransform
                    attributeName="transform"
                    attributeType="XML"
                    type="scale"
                    from="0"
                    to="1"
                    begin="indefinite"
                    dur="1s"
                    fill="freeze" />
                  <animate id="hg4"
                    attributeName="opacity"
                    values="0;1"
                    dur="1s"
                    begin="indefinite"
                    fill="freeze" />

                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
```

I already tried other questions solutions but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform-origin) attribute on the element that is going to be transformed (here on the `<g>`).

The value of your begin attribute was `begin="indefinite"`, but that is not a valid value. Should be time or an event ([begin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin)).

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
  <g transform="scale(0)" opacity="0" transform-origin="5 5">
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="blue"/>
    <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform"
      attributeType="XML"
      type="scale"
      from="0"
      to="1"
      dur="1s"
      fill="freeze" />
    <animate id="hg4"
      attributeName="opacity"
      values="0;1"
      dur="1s"
      fill="freeze" />
  </g>
</svg>
```